# Impala connection management best practice

Tags: impala

I want to use Cloudera Impala within Clodera Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.10.0 in order to execute some queries in java with best performance under high-load conditions.

I have already read official documentation https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-10-x/topics/impala_jdbc.html but there are a few moments I didn't understand clearly.
I have use Hive dependency in order to connect to Impala

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
   <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.0-cdh5.10.0</version>
   <classifier>standalone</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Now please tell me what is a best way to create and dispose Impala connections:

- Should I use `DriverManager.getConnection` inside try-with-resource block? Will it cause new physical connection creating for each query? Another words, is that a heavy operation to create connection this way?
- Is there connection pool on server side? Should I use `DataSource.getConnection` (just like in JavaEE) or something else in order to use this connection pool?
- Or should I use some 3rd-part libraries like `org.apache.commons:commons-dbcp2` to create connection pool on client side?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Cloudera provides a JDBC driver (type 4.1) for Impala, with 30+ pages of documentation. Why don't you just download that driver, instead of trying to recompile the Apache Hive JDBC driver (type 3, with limited compliance to JDBC standards, bad backwards/forward compatibility, very poor documentation) and hoping that it will be 100% aligned with the exact wire protocol used by your exact Impala version??

Comment: Thanks for you answer. 
I was confusing because there is no maven dependency for ImpalaJDBC driver so I need to download it manuallу and import it to my maven repository in order to use it. And hive-jdbc works out-of-box so I start to use it. But I understand you, I will try. 
What about the main question from me about the best way to get connection?

Comment: About dependencies > Cloudera driver uses a commercial JDBC SDK (from Simba), no source code available. About connection pools > no idea. Only used that driver for standalone batch jobs. But again, check the PDF documentation...